# Group By or Distinct in a multi table query

Tags: sql

I have this query as follows, It returns the correct result, but I would like to use GROUP BY or DISTINCT to narrow the selection down on `lnk_ID` (3rd column)

I have tried them both, but it fails every time.

```
SELECT  dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
ORDER BY dmg.dmg_Surname, dmg.dmg_FirstName, lnk.lnk_ID;





Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Richard Airey   566105926   15/01/2015 00:00:00 Male    Tayside
Richard Airey   566105926   15/01/2015 00:00:00 Male    Tayside
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
Nuha    Abdelwahab  566106181   16/07/2015 00:00:00     Tayside
Patricia    Agnew   566106230   17/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Dumfries and Galloway
Richard Airey   566105926   15/01/2015 00:00:00 Male    Tayside
Aileen  Allan   566105477   25/09/2015 00:00:00 Female  Forth Valley
```

**THE FOLLOWING FAILED**

```
SELECT  dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        DISTINCT (lnk.lnk_ID),
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
```

**AND**

```
SELECT  dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
GROUP BY lnk.lnk_ID;
```

Comment: Narrow how? Show us the expected result.

Comment: In the result you can see many duplicate names. Id like DISTINCT LNK_ID values across the result. Will post something in a min.

Comment: According to your output it looks like simply switching to `SELECT DISTINCT` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT --< Here !
        dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
ORDER BY dmg.dmg_Surname, dmg.dmg_FirstName, lnk.lnk_ID;
```

OR

```
SELECT  MAX(dmg.dmg_FirstName  ) As dmg_FirstName, --< Aggregate
        MAX(dmg.dmg_Surname    ) As dmg_Surname,   --< all 
        lnk.lnk_ID,                                --< but GROUP BY expression
        MAX(dlk.dlk_AssessDate ) As dlk_AssessDate,
        MAX(dmg.dmg_Sex        ) As dmg_Sex,
        MAX(trn.ScotHealthboard) As ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
GROUP BY lnk.lnk_ID;
```

Comment: I feel silly. Thanks. need to brush up on my SQL definitely.

Comment: I will need to give Ben the tic though, as hes answered first. did upvote you though.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to remove duplicate rows from your query, I believe all you need to do is put the keyword DISTINCT after the word SELECT (i.e. SELECT DISTINCT dmg.dmg_FirstName...

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but it does not work. I'll put a example that I tried.

Comment: @Y.B. Thanks for the offer but no worries - you did a more complete job with yours :)

Comment: @Y.B. Oh, and your use of the aggregates (your second approach) was actually kind of cool - with I had thought of that!  :)